# Is it possible to parse all tweets of user?

Tags: rest, twitter, tweets, twitter-rest-api

For example, I want to parse all tweets of [Microsoft](https://twitter.com/microsoft) .

Twitter has API - [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline). But how I can see, This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets.

So, can I parse all tweets of some `screen_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be a bit better with [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), adding the query `q=@Microsoft`.

However, you will have problems as well:

1. You'll get all tweets mentioning @Microsoft, not only the ones at the `user_timeline`. You will have to filter afterwards
2. Although there is not limit in theory, as the one of 3200 of `GET statuses/user_timeline`, you probably *wont* be able to get *all* tweets from a user. By definition, Twitter API does not provide that kind of service. If you want *all* tweets you'll need to use a service like [topsy](http://topsy.com/) **(not free)**
3. You'll have to use pagination since every query to `GET search/tweets` gives you a maximum of 100 tweets, and if you need to get more than 450*100 tweets (remember you'll get a mixture of tweets as pointed out in 1. above), you'll have to handle [Twitter rate limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) and launch your queries in windows of 15 minutes

Sorry there is not a simpler answer to your question... Hope it helps anyway.

(EDIT: 450*100 is assuming you use [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only). If not, it is 180*100)

Comment: thank you for response. As I understand it, I can't get all tweets even using the browser.

Comment: Well, Twitter does not guarantee you'll get *all* tweets. However, in my experience, it is good enough...